# Disable chrome.exe Volume Control

Tags: windows-10, audio

I recently got new update from windows.
It really annoys me the new look of the audio sound display.
Its really big and i get unnecessary information like from where audio comes and to have next and previous button. 
The previous one was simple and much better.
Is there a way I can roll back to the old one, just to display the sound bar ?

[the new audio look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOkZF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution online. 
I was wrong, this new look was from google chrome update not from windows. 
At the fallowing link there are 2 steps to disable and get back the old simple look.
[Disable chrome.exe Volume Control](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/134484-enable-disable-chrome-exe-volume-control-media-key-handling.html)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to stop updating, and Microsoft releases updates to fix bugs and to update features. Things like this happen on almost any OS. The only way you might be able to do this is if you go into the settings app, Update and Security, Recovery, then go back to the previous build, or you could go into Windows Update, view update history, uninstall updates, and uninstall the one that was installed. Be aware though that if you do this your computer will most likely not be as secure, as that is what a lot of the updates are for.